# Unable to Set Session Preset While Capture Session Running in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code that no longer works in iOS 7 for changing the sessionPreset of a capture session while it is still running (but not capturing video). This worked on iOS 6.x, but on 7 the video preview freezes.

I've tried removing begin/commit configuration, as well as locking the input device and unlocking after. I've also tried calling beginSession again after the commitConfiguration, but this causes the device to start capturing video.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
- (void)setVideoCaptureSessionPreset:(NSString *)videoCaptureSessionPreset
{
    if (_captureSession.sessionPreset == videoCaptureSessionPreset) return;

    if (![_captureSession canSetSessionPreset:videoCaptureSessionPreset])
    {
        TFLog(@"%s Device cannot set preset to: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, videoCaptureSessionPreset);
        return;
    }

    [_captureSession beginConfiguration];
    _captureSession.sessionPreset = videoCaptureSessionPreset;
    [_captureSession commitConfiguration];
}
```

Edit: Not only does this cause the video preview to freeze, it causes the entire phone lock up (background no longer displayed on home screen, app cannot restart, and eventually the entire phone has to be hard-reset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7 and up, the solution is to use the new `AVCaptureDevice activeFormat` API and set the session preset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority`. When you change the active format, you have to wrap your `startRunning` in the `lockForConfiguration` like so:

```
if ([_videoCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil])
{
    _videoCaptureDevice.activeFormat = format
    [_captureSession startRunning];
    [_videoCaptureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```